# Checkbox renders fine in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox, chromium

Can anybody tell me why in [this example](http://jsbin.com/urodit/73/edit) the checkboxes and the text beside it are rendered differently in Chrome as opposed to in Firefox(the desired result)?

```
Firefox 16.0.2
Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367) (WebKit 535.19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put `<br>` at the end of the same line as your first checkbox input element instead of on the next line. This will horizontally align the checkboxes.
   See also: [text-align: right has margin or buffer in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570447/text-align-right-has-margin-or-buffer-in-chrome)
2. Adjust the width of both input elements in that form to `1em`. Chrome seems to automatically expand the width of these to the available space in the container while Firefox does not.

This is not a complete fix yet though, there is still a difference in the vertical positioning.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/urodit/83/edit).